# Spherical image of 1 sheeted hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, differential

The 1-sheeted hyperboloid $-(x_1 ^2 /a^2)+x_2 ^2 +......X_{n+1}^2 =1 $ , $ (a>0)$.
What happen to the spherical image when $ a\rightarrow  \infty $ ? when $a\rightarrow 0 $ ?

Comment: I have calculate grad(f(p))/ norm(grad(f(p))) ,after that i could not find way to solve it..so if anyone help me that would be great.

Comment: I guess you don't mean $a>1$ if you're going to allow $a\to 0$? I suspect you meant $a>0$. Think more geometrically. Think about the cone $$-x_1^2/a^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_{n+1}^2=0$$ to which the hyperboloid is asymptotic. [It might help to start with $n=1$ and $n=2$, where you can really draw it.] As a check, you should convince yourself that as $a\to\infty$, the surface approaches a spherical cylinder (so what's the spherical image for that?), and that as $a\to 0$, the surfaces approaches a pair of parallel planes (so what's the spherical image for that?).